# QT - Unit Test for UI

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test and find out if the message is actually displayed, I don’t understand how to get the value sent by the function DoWork. I use google tests.

```
class Printer
{


    signals:
        void Print(QString message);
    private:
        void DoWork()
       {
        //
        if (isError)
            emit Print("Error");

       }
}
```

Auto Generate by qt:

```
void Printer::Print(QString t1) {
     void *_a[] = { nullptr, const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(std::addressof(_t1))) };
        QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, _a);
}
```

Comment: How is UI involved here?

Comment: Auto Generation from QT

Comment: Please you need to be more clear in your question, snippet and comments. It's not clear at all about you are talking about